# Random Generator from String Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using Java for this problem. Does anyone know how to randomly take 2 questions out of 3 question String array? Lets say I have a 3x5 string array like this:

```
String TestBank[][] = {{"What color is grass?","A. Green","B. Red","C. Pink","A"},
{"Whats the first month called?","A. December","B. January","C. March","B"},
{"What shape is a soccer ball?","A. square","B. flat","C. round","C"}};
```

The first column is the question, 2nd-4th column is the answer choices, and the 5th column is the correct answer. I'm trying to figure out how to randomly get 2 questions from these 3 and store those 2 questions into a one dimensional array of 2 rows in which we use the JOptionPane, for outputting, in which takes those questions from the one dimensional array and shows each question separately one by one in different windows with the answer choices included. And after answering the 2 questions, it tells the user the score based off how many questions he/she missed.

I'm relatively new to Java and it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me with this.

Comment: You can use `Random`'s `nextInt(int n)`. Have a look at the api [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: I read the link you sent me but it seems really confusing to me. I'm really new to Java so I'm not really code efficient if you know what I mean. If you or anyone could create an example based off the information I put down and explain it to me that would be really helpful. I'm a visual learner basically.

Comment: Hello Blue, welcome to SO. You would normally want to be a bit more precise in your question. What part of your question do you have problems with (selecting the random questions, how to put those into an array, how to use JOptionPane, how to show that in a window, how to tell the user the score, something else)? What have you tried already? Why was that not working? Why did the "Related questions" on the side not help you?

Comment: Hello. I know how to use JOptionPane and how to tell the user the score. I just don't know how to pull 2 questions randomly from the 3 in the 2-d array and store them into the 1-d array and then have them shown in separate windows. Kind of like a test generator. They helped for some instances but I'm really new to computer programming so you cant just be like here's this and this..enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use random class in your case. Choose a random integer, where the highest number chosen by random is your total number of questions.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomQuestion = random.nextInt(nrOfQuestions);
```

and you use this randomQuestion variable to access you question from the matrix:
testBank[randomQuestion][0]

Cheers!

Comment: So how do I assign numbers to my questions?

Comment: PS: variable names, in Java standards, starts with lower case.

Comment: well, you have a matrix, array of arrays, and you said that you store your questions on the first column of every row. So the total number of questions is actually the total number of rows you have in the matrix.

Comment: Yes the questions are stored on the first column of every row, but I want to randomly get 2 question from the 3 and store those 2 into a one dimensional array and when doing the JOptionPane for my output, I want to call each question separately one by one from the one dimensional array and I don't know how to do any of that. I got the answer from @aurelianus above, but I don't know how or where to put these into my code. I'm sorry for not understanding this and I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: This only shows how to get 1 random question. This answer does not protect against repetition of a question either. It does therefore not fully answer the question.

Comment: that is the main part, I think he is capable to do the rest of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling and then shortening the array is probably the way to go. This is more easily done on lists however. In general collection classes should be preferred over arrays.

Most of the work in this answer is performed to convert the arrays to a list and back again.

```
private static String[][] randomize(String[][] testBank, int questions) {
    // convert top array to list of mutable size 
    List<String[]> testBankAsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[] qoa: testBank) {
        testBankAsList.add(qoa);
    }

    // randomize questions
    Collections.shuffle(testBankAsList, new SecureRandom());

    // remove the tail
    testBankAsList.subList(questions, testBankAsList.size()).clear();

    // convert back into array
    String[][] shorterRandomTestBank = testBankAsList.toArray(new String[testBankAsList.size()][]);

    return shorterRandomTestBank;
}
```

Where `questions` should be set to 2 of course. I left out all the parameter checking.

Note that `Arrays.toList` cannot be used as it simply creates a list over the backing array, and therefore the `clear()` operation will fail.

Example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testBank[][] = {{"What color is grass?","A. Green","B. Red","C. Pink","A"},
            {"Whats the first month called?","A. December","B. January","C. March","B"},
            {"What shape is a soccer ball?","A. square","B. flat","C. round","C"}};
    int questions = 2;

    String[][] shorterRandomTestBank = randomize(testBank, questions);

    // iterate of the returned questions
    for (String[] qoa : shorterRandomTestBank) {
        // prints the question
        System.out.println(qoa[0]);

        // prints the answer
        System.out.println(qoa[qoa.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

Sorry, I'll let you do the Swing / GUI programming yourself. If you get into trouble with that ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that handles the possibility that the random generator generates the same question twice. With the code below you will only ever get 1 question asked. Also I have commented each step to give you an idea of the logic. One small point if you had a 1D array of type int, then you would run into problem during the check. This is because 1D arrays of type int set the default value to 0. Using Integer or an ArrayList eliminates this problem because default value is null and not 0.

I have also included the loop and JOptionPane code required to display the randomly chosen question. It is up to you to decide what you want to do with the responses.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    // We are setting this final variable because we don't want to hard code numbers into loops etc
    final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS_TO_TAKE = 2;

    String testBank[][] = {{"What color is grass?", "A. Green", "B. Red", "C. Pink", "A"},
            {"Whats the first month called?", "A. December", "B. January", "C. March", "B"},
            {"What shape is a soccer ball?", "A. square", "B. flat", "C. round", "C"}};

    // Initialise the array of questions that have been randomly chosen.
    String finalArrayOfQuestions[] = new String[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS_TO_TAKE];

    // ArrayList to store the index number of a question so we can check later if it has been already used by number generator
    ArrayList<Integer> alreadyChosenList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // boolean that we will use for whether or not a question has already been selected
    boolean alreadyChosen;

    // The column number that the random number generator generates, which is then used to extract the String question
    int rowToUse;

    // A for loop is used to loop through the process, depending on how many questions you want to take.
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS_TO_TAKE; i++) {

        // Generate a random number, repeat the process (do/while) until a random number has been generated that hasnt been generated before
        do {
            // Generate a random number within the range
            Random random = new Random();
            rowToUse = random.nextInt(testBank.length);

            //check not already been picked
            alreadyChosen = alreadyChosen(rowToUse, alreadyChosenList);
        } while (alreadyChosen);


        // Get String representation of question chosen at random
        String questionChosen = testBank[rowToUse][0];

        // Add this String to finalListOfQuestions
        finalArrayOfQuestions[i] = questionChosen;

        // adds to list of questions already chosen. Makes sure you don't take same question twice.
        //alreadyChosenList[i] = alreadyChosenList[rowToUse];
        alreadyChosenList.add(rowToUse);
    }

    for (String questions : finalArrayOfQuestions) {
        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(questions);

        /*
        The response is the answer that the user types in. Here you can check it against the arrays you have
        Or if you dont want the user to input a response use:
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, questions);
         */

    }
}


/*
Method takes row index to use and the ArrayList of row indexes already been used and returns true or false depending if the current one is in the arraylist
 */
private static boolean alreadyChosen(int rowToUse, ArrayList<Integer> alreadyChosenList) {

    for (int indexToCheck : alreadyChosenList) {
        if (indexToCheck == rowToUse) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```